# method calss error TypeError: __init__() missing 4 required positional arguments:

Tags: python

I got error in the terminal regarding a method class

this my code

```
class Employee:

    def __init__(self, f_name, l_name, id_number, address, salary):
        self.f_name = f_name
        self.l_name = l_name
        self.id_number = id_number
        self.address = address
        self.salary = salary

    @classmethod
    def split_the_data(cls, data):
        split_data = data.split(':')
        return cls(split_data[0])

emp1 = Employee("j", "H", "123", "blabla", "1000")
print(emp1.f_name)

data_1 = "name:age:address"
emp2 = Employee.split_the_data(data_1)
```

and this is the error that i got

```
 emp2 = Employee.split_the_data(data_1)
 return cls(split_data[0])
TypeError: __init__() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'l_name', 'id_number', 'address', and 'salary'
j
```

I'm not sure where is the error exactly but this only happen when i declare
`emp2 = Employee.split_the_data(data_1)`

Comment: The class `__init__` method takes 5 positional arguments but you only pass 1 in the `split_the_data` method

Comment: but it's a class method

Comment: Not sure what you mean, this line in the classmethod `return cls(split_data[0])` tries to create and return an instance of the class but only passes 1 argument

Comment: What did you expect to happen?  You essentially try to create `Employee('name')`

Comment: It's method that make a list of a string and return position number zero
and this is the string ```data_1 = "name:age:address"```

Comment: If you want to return the first part of split string, why there's `cls()` involved at all?

Comment: this is just a tutorial that i was watching and the instructor made class method and was trying to explain it
so i'm trying to understand the class method

Comment: Look closely at `return cls(split_data[0])` and figure out what it actually does.

Comment: this isn't my code it's a tutorial code so let make sure i understood it right
so the instructor made a class method that return data_1[0]

Comment: No they did not.  Your code returns an instance of `Employee` class (`return cls(...)`)